# converting a numeric array to an associative

Tags: php, json

The following JSON structure:

```
{
    "details":
    [
        {"specific_exercise.distance" : "14",},
        {"specific_exercise.avg_pace" : "7.5"}
    ]
}
```

converts to this when using json_decode():

```
stdClass Object
(
    [details] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [specific_exercise.distance] => 14
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [specific_exercise.avg_pace] => 7.5
                )
        )
)
```

Instead I'd like to have this converted into this:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [details] => Array
        (
            [specific_exercise.distance] => 14
            [specific_exercise.avg_pace] => 7.5
        )

)
```

What's the best way to convert from the json_decode() structure to the more effective PHP structure?

Comment: You'll have to iterate and replace stuff manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing your JSON probably will be better solution if you have control over that, for example

```
{
    "details":
    {
        "specific_exercise.distance" : "14",
        "specific_exercise.avg_pace" : "7.5"
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Then you can use this method:

```
function parseJsonFormat($json)
{
    $json_object = json_decode($json);
    $details_result = array();
    foreach($json_object['details'] as $detail)
    {
         $details_result = array_merge($details_result, get_object_vars($detail));
    }
    $json_object['details'] = $details_result;
    return $json_object;
}
```

You can further modify the method to work for each array not just details key.

Comment: Yes that's precisely what I wanted to do. Sadly there are some technical reasons I can't. :(

Answer (score 2):

To slam together multiple associative subarrays use:

```
 call_user_func_array("array_merge", (array)$subarray)
```

Where `$subarray` means `details` in your case, where you assign the result back.

Only works on arrays, not objects, so best to instruct `json_decode` with the second parameter first.